# A probability problem with two uniformly distributed random variables

Tags: probability

Please consider the following problem and my soltuion to it. I would like to know where I went wrong.
Thanks,
Bob

Problem:
Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variable each uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. Find
$P(|\frac{x}{y}-1|\leq .5)$.
Answer:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Big|\frac{x}{y}-1\Big|\leq .5 &\iff& -0.5 \leq \frac{x}{y} -1 \leq 0.5 \\
P\Big(\Big|\frac{x}{y}-1 \Big| \leq .5\Big) &=& P\Big(\frac{x}{y}-1 \leq .5\Big) - P\Big(1 - \frac{x}{y} \leq -.5\Big) \\
P\Big(\Big|\frac{x}{y}-1 \Big| \leq .5\Big) &=& P\Big(\frac{x}{y}-1 \leq .5\Big) - P\Big(\frac{x}{y} - 1 \geq 0.5\Big) \\
%
P\Big(\frac{x}{y}-1 \leq .5\Big) &=& P\Big(\frac{x}{y} \leq 1.5\Big) = P( x \leq 1.5y ) \\
P\Big(\frac{x}{y}-1 \leq .5\Big) &=& \int_0^1 \int_{0}^{1.5y} 1 \,\, dx \,\, dy \\
P\Big(\frac{x}{y}-1 \leq .5\Big) &=& \int_0^1 1.5y \,\, dy = \frac{3y^2}{4} \Big|_0^1 \\
P\Big(\frac{x}{y}-1 \leq .5\Big) &=& \frac{3}{4} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now we need to find $P\Big(\frac{x}{y} - 1 \geq 0.5\Big)$
\begin{eqnarray*}
P\Big(\frac{x}{y} - 1 \geq 0.5\Big) &=& 1 - P\Big(\frac{x}{y} - 1 \leq 0.5\Big) \\
P\Big(\frac{x}{y} - 1 \leq 0.5\Big) &=& P\Big(\frac{x}{y} - \leq 1.5\Big) = P( x \leq 1.5y ) \\
P( x \leq 1.5y ) &=& \int_0^1 \int_0^{1.5y} \, dx \,\, dy = \int_0^1 \frac{3y}{2} dy \\
P( x \leq 1.5y ) &=& \frac{3y^2}{4} \Big|_0^1 = \frac{1}{4} \\
P\Big(\frac{x}{y} - 1 \geq 0.5\Big) &=& 1 - \frac{3}{4} = \frac{1}{4} \\
P\Big(\Big|\frac{x}{y}-1 \Big| \leq .5\Big) &=& \frac{3}{4} - \frac{1}{4} \\
P\Big(\Big|\frac{x}{y}-1 \Big| \leq .5\Big) &=& \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
However, the book's answer is: $\frac{5}{12}$.

Comment: $P(x\le 1.5y)$ should be $P(x\le min(1.5y,1))$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}$ is the answer you get when you ignore the fact that $0\le x\le 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$-0.5\le \frac{x}{y}-1\le 0.5$ or $-0.5y\le x-y\le 0.5y$ or $0.5y\le x\le 1.5y$.  The probability is $P=\int_0^1 \int_{.5y}^{min (1,1.5y)}dxdy=\int_0^\frac{2}{3}ydy+\int_{\frac{2}{3}}^1(1-.5y)dy=\frac{5}{12}$.

Note: answer is different from book.

Comment: I did a simulation; your answer looks right.

Comment: @J.G. What was the sample size for the simulation?

Comment: @herb.steinberg $10,000$; its estimate was $0.4167$.

Comment: Standard deviation is approximately $0.005$  so $\frac{3}{8}$ is definitely ruled out.

Comment: I ran the following simulation in R:  y = runif(8000000)
                                                      x = runif(8000000)
                                                     sum( abs(x/y - 1) < 0.5  ) / length(x)
The result is 0.4164.

Comment: $\frac{5}{12}$ = 0.4166666666666.....

Comment: I copied the answer from the back of the book incorrectly. The book gets $\frac{5}{12}$ also.

Comment: @ Bob  Hooray!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your first equation is wrong.

It holds:

$$\Big|\frac{x}{y}-1\Big|\leq 0.5 \iff -0.5 \le \frac{x}{y}-1 \le 0.5$$

So it follows:
$$\begin{align*}P\Big(\Big|\frac{x}{y}-1\Big|\leq 0.5\Big) &= P\Big(\frac{x}{y}-1\leq 0.5\Big) -  P\Big(\frac{x}{y}-1\leq -0.5\Big)\\ &= P\Big(\frac{x}{y}-1\leq 0.5\Big) -  P\Big(1-\frac{x}{y}\geq 0.5\Big) \\ &= P\Big(\frac{x}{y}-1\leq 0.5\Big) -  1 + P\Big(1-\frac{x}{y}\leq 0.5\Big)\end{align*}$$

Comment: I updated my post based upon your answer. However, I still get the wrong answer.

Comment: There is no change in your post. Consider the additional "-1" in my equation.Then it holds $$\begin{align*}P\left(\frac{x}{y} - 1 \le 0.5\right) &= P(x \le 1.5y)\\ &= \int_0^1\int_0 ^\min(1,1.5y) dx dy\\ &= \frac{2}{3}\end{align*}$$ and $$\begin{align*}P\left(1 - \frac{x}{y} \le 0.5\right) &= P(0.5y \le x)\\ &= \int_0^1\int_{0.5y} ^1 dx dy\\ &= \frac{3}{4}\end{align*}$$ and so we get $$P\Big(\Big|\frac{x}{y}-1\Big|\leq 0.5\Big) = \frac{2}{3} - 1 + \frac{3}{4} = \frac{5}{12}$$ like herb steinberg already calculated.